# Why won't heroku work with proxy in my react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, mongoose

I have a simple notes app that uses react(create react app) in a client folder with a node express mongoose back end. If I try to upload to heroku it rejects it because of the proxy ("proxy": "http://localhost:3001") in the package.json in the client folder. If I get rid of the proxy it will upload to heroku no problem but because it's not there it won't talk to the back end so nothing works. When pushing to heroku with the proxy it will build but the app gives me "Invalid Host header". How do I go about fixing this?  All I have tried is deleting the proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I had a misspelled index.js document in my models folder and that's what was giving me the Invalid Host Header error. I had a capital I instead of lowercase...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a fixed port in your app? Heroku assigns you a dynamic port that you must bind to, so you can't simply use a fixed port like 3001.

You should bind to process.env.PORT when running on Heroku instead. See [runtime principles](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles).

Comment: I for some reason didn't have it as process.env.PORT but I am still getting Invalid Host header when I open the app.

Comment: Have you tried setting the HOST environment variable for your heroku app to the domain you're using through heroku?

Comment: How would I set that up? Would it be a .env in the root folder with HOST = https://react-notes-project.herokuapp.com/ ?

Comment: Since the configuration is specific to the Heroku instance you would want to go to Heroku, navigate to your app, click "Settings", click "Reveal Config Vars" and then add it there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a build pack that works around this problems and offer a better experience with `create-react-app` check it out:

- https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

Just create your application by running:

```
heroku create <app name> --buildpack mars/create-react-app
```

Comment: With this I am getting a 404 when I open the app. I moved everything to a new folder and created a new heroku app.